# How to save my data in iOS document folder?

Tags: ios

My application need to save data to my local database. The reason why I want to save it to document folder is I want the data shared by all devices with the same iCloud account. What I normally do is to copy the empty database from my Bundle into my document folder the first time when the app launch. But I'm not very sure it will be rejected by Apple or not? (Because one of my app which preloading a database into document folder was rejected.) Do you have better strategy? (I know I can save the data into library folder. But the data will not be synchronized then.)

Thanks.

Comment: the reason why you're not allowed to write to the document folder right away is because you're only allowed to put user content there. But what you can actually do is wait with the instantiation of your database until the user actually starts filling it with his content. Then you're allowed by Apple to put data there! You should should also make sure that the database is not too bloated, so Apple won't complain about that either!

Comment: Actually the database will be the user content although it's empty at first.

Comment: yes, but even an empty database is a file and therefore is not allowed by apple and they will reject. But if you put the database in as soon as the user generates the first content its allowed!